# Insert related field django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this simple model and I am having difficult in inserting related field of 'notes' through django rest framework.

```
class Student(models.Model):
   firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   prefLocation = models.ManyToManyField("Location", blank=True, null=True, related_name = 'prefLocation')

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.firstName

class LocationRegion(models.Model):
    regionName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.regionName

class Location(models.Model):
    locationName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.ForeignKey(LocationRegion, null=True, blank=True, related_name='locations')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.locationName

class Note(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=True, blank=True, related_name='notes')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

I am unsure if I need to use ModelSerializer or generic Serializer. Validated_data doesn't return 'note' field in the deserialized data. I would appreciate any help with the serializer.

Thanks

Here are my serializers :

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        def get_notes(self, obj):
            return validated_data['note']

        note = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_notes')
        return Candidate.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'note')

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Note
```

Comment: What does your StudentSerializer look like?

Comment: You will probably want to have a NoteSerializer

and then inside your StudentSerializer:  notes = NoteSerializer()

But its hard to say for sure without the actual Serializers here

Comment: I have edited my post to show my serializers. Thanks.